# I don't know how to code the path in the POST request for my simple login form app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, post

I have a simple login form app in node.js. I am able to display the login form and enter login data but my POST request to capture the login data doesn't work, I get `POST http://localhost:3000/client 404 (Not Found)` error at the js console. I think I am coding the path wrong in the post request. My HTML code for the login form is in the `client.html` file and my js code is in the `server.js` file. I am providing both.

Here is my client.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Havuzlu Site main page</title>
    
    <style>
        /* Use havuzlusite picture as full page background. */ 
        html {
            background-image: url("/havuzlusite-img.jpg"); 
            background-repeat: no-repeat; 
            background-position: center center; 
            background-attachment: fixed; 
            background-size: cover; 
        }

        h1 {
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        /* Set general style for the button class. */
        .button {
            border: none;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }  
        
        /* Create classes for main page buttons. */
        .bldgnews-btn {background-color: aqua; margin-left: 39%;}
        .bldgmngmt-btn {background-color: blue; margin: center;}
        .login-btn {background-color: blueviolet; margin-right: 39%;} 

        /* The popup login form - hidden by default */
        .login-form {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 15px;
            border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
            z-index: 9;
            max-width: 300px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: white;
        }

        /* Set styling for the input fields of the login-form. */
        .login-form input[type=text], .login-form input[type=password] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
            border: none;
            background: #f1f1f1;
        }

        /* Set additional styling When the input fields get focus (when they are clicked). */
        .login-form input[type=text]:focus, .login-form input[type=password]:focus {
            background-color: #ddd;
            outline: none;
        }

        /* Set styling for the login button. */
        .login-form .login-btn {
            background-color: #04AA6D;
            color: white;
            padding: 16px 20px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        /* Add a red background color to the cancel button */
        .login-form .cancel-btn {
            background-color: red;
        }

        /* Add some hover effects to buttons */
        .login-form .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }

  </style>  
</head>  
 
<body>
    <! Create main page. >
    <h1>Havuzlu siteye hoş geldiniz</h1>
    <button class="bldgnews-btn" type="submit">Site haberleri</button>
    <button class="bldgmngmt-btn" type="submit">Site yönetimi</button>
    <button class="login-btn" onclick="openLoginForm()">Aidat takibi</button>

    <! Create login form. > 
    <form class="login-form" id="loginForm" action="http://localhost:3000/client" 
     method="POST"> 
        <h1>Kullanıcı girişi</h1>
        <label for="isim"><b>isim</b></label> >
        <input type="text" placeholder="İlk ve soy isim giriniz" id="isim" name="isim" 
          required>
        <label for="sifre"><b>şifre</b></label> >
        <input type="password" placeholder="Şifre giriniz" id="sifre" name="sifre" required>
        <button type="submit" class="login-btn">Giriş</button> >
        <button type="button" class="cancel-btn" onclick="close-Form()"> Kapat</button>
    </form>
        
    <script>
        function openLoginForm() {
            document.getElementById("loginForm").style.display = "block";
        }
        function closeForm() {
            document.getElementById("loginForm").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
    <script>src="/server.js"</script>
  </body>  
  </html>
```

Here is my server.js file:

```js
//import express, { static, urlencoded } from "express";  
const express = require('express');  // Import Express package
const app = express();  // Create an Express app variable so that we can use Express in 
anywhere.

const router = express.Router();
// add router in express app
app.use("/",router);

//import path from "path";
const path = require('path');

// Import body-parser module to parse incoming requests
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//import cors from "cors";  
const cors = require('cors');

const port = 3000;  //Set port to 3000. 

// Below, we use the modules that we imported.
app.use(express.json() );   // use Express module body-parser to parse JSON-encoded request 
bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); // use Express module body-parser to parse URL- 
encoded request bodies
app.use(cors());

// Send the local image file to be used as app homepage background, to the client. 
app.get('/havuzlusite-img.jpg', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("D:/Behrans-files/Web-projects/havuzlusite/havuzlusite-img.jpg"); 
});

// Send html code for app homepage and login page, to the client.
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("D:/Behrans-files/Web-projects/havuzlusite/client.html");
});

//Route for login. When the user clicks Login button, we will post the //request to server and 
//get the response.
//router.post('/client', (req, res) => {
app.post('http://localhost:3000/client', (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body); 
    console.log(req.body.sifre); 
    res.end("yes");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("server is running at http://127.0.0.1:", port);   
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

`app.post` should only take the path, not the entire URL (just like you did with `app.get):

```js
app.post('/client', (req, res) =>{
    // Here^
    console.log(req.body); 
    console.log(req.body.sifre); 
    res.end("yes");
});
```

Comment: I did try it your way before and it didn't work. That is why I coded it this way. But now it works, I don't know what other changes I made that caused it to work this time. Thanks very much.

Comment: Hello again. In my client.html file, I have the two js functions in <script> tags and it works. However, my preference is to place these two functions m in my server.js file. But when I do this it doesn't work and I get not found error at the js console. Any help regarding will be appreciated.